# How can I thank somebody for pointing out my mistakes?

Tags: politeness

Thanking and apologizing in several forms is essential in a Japanese working environment. I currently have the following list that I have picked up from mails amongst my Japanese coworkers but I'm curious what could be other examples to do this...

- Thanks for pointing out my mistakes.

  ご指導を頂き、ありがとうございました。

  丁寧にご指導を頂き、ありがとうございました。

  丁寧にご指導を頂きまして有難うごいざいました
- Thanks for the feedback!

  添削ありがとうございます. とても助かります.

  意味を間違っておりました。教えていただきありがとうございます。

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 有難うごいざいました must be a typo for 有難うございました, which is the kanji notation for ありがとうございました.  Using kanji here is a little old-fashioned.

Comment: Could we get some romaji for these for us learners please? We need to thank people too (-:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would also use "ご指摘、ありがとうございます。"

指摘　has meaning pointing out, and 指導 is more like guidance.

Answer (score 4):

You could also say 「ありがとう。勉強になりました」, which works out to something like "Thanks for teaching me"